# Sending group email using AWS SES

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses

I am working on nodejs with AWS SES and i have come across a scenerio in which I have to create a custom group which contains multiple email Id's and when I write group name in destination, then it sends email to all the email ids in that group.

Ex- Group named testGroup is created with emails{abc@gmail.com , efg@gmail.com , xyz@gmail.com}.

```
let params = {Destination: {ToAddresses: ['testGroup'],
```

then, ses.sendEmail()

Please tell me if, It is possible to create such emailgroups in AWS SES. If yes, then how can i send such email.

Application- Newsletter subscriptions.

I am also open to sending an custom email to all users of a AWS-Cognito userpool, if above solution isn't feasible.